# nservice bus publish not making it to queue

Tags: nservicebus, publish-subscribe

I have 2 different types that I'm publishing to the same queue. One of these types publishes as expected while the other doesn't even make it to the queue. These objects are in the same dll and reside in the same namespace.

Has anyone else experienced a situation like this?

Comment: Post more info: what does the log say?  What version of NSB?  Which persistence and transport technologies are you using?

Comment: I'm using nservicebus 5 with RavenDB and MSMQ. The log isn't showing any errors

Comment: By "publishing to the same queue", you mean both messages are subscribed to by the same service, right?  Check the logs on both the publisher and subscriber ends if you haven't already.

Comment: Also, if you know how, check that the subscriptions in RavenDB look correct.

Comment: Is this all on the same machine or different machines?

Comment: Yes, it's subscribed to by the same service, the ravenDB subscriptions look like they are correct and they are on the same machine. I'm running it on my local dev machine.

Comment: Was this working at one point and now stopped?  If so, the structure of the message may have changed (although I think the log would have an error).  Confirm that the dll with the message types on the publisher matches the dll on the subscriber?

Comment: I had it working with the one message and that is still working. I've never been able to get the second message to go through however, even though it's set up the same way.

Comment: My last comment could not be the cause, then (you would not have a subscription).  Two recommendations: (1) pore over the logs, not just when the message gets sent/received, but also at startup for the two endpoints, (2) post your question to the NSB mailing list, which will hit a wider audience of people who can help (https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/particularsoftware)

Comment: Did you add a message handler in your subscriber for the second message?

Comment: Please also show us what you use to identify your events. Are you inheriting from IEvent or are you using conventions. If you are using conventions how do they look like so that we can help you out solve your issues as soon as possible.

Comment: I'm defining the events using the Conventions.DefiningEventsAs in my endpointConfig. Also, I'm using one ravenDB to persist nservicebus and anotherone to feed a website. It looks like the subscriptions are being stored in the web database instead of the nservicebus database. I can figure out why this is.

Comment: So the problem was that I had nservicebus initializing the document store for my web database, which was somehow getting its wires crossed with the nservicebus database. I ripped this out and initialized the web db document store on its own and it started to work.

Comment: Thanks everyone for your input!

Comment: @BobKarman I think users of SO would really appreciate if you provide the answer to your question as an answer here (not in the comments) and then mark your answer as the answer to your question (wow that was a complex sentence).

Answer (score 0):

So the problem was that I had nservicebus initializing the document store for my web database, which was somehow getting its wires crossed with the nservicebus database. I ripped this out and initialized the web db document store on its own and it started to work.